# jQuery nested tab design issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In internet explorer the nested tab is displaying with black dot. Through inspect element if i did any changes in css the dot will be gone. If i do a refresh again it is coming. I don't know how to resolve.[Demo is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/0m2zdo20/2/)Following is the snippet I have used for creating the nested tab.
Thanks in advance..

```
 <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Total Pool Point </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="t">Vessel Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" id="t">Standard Voyages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4" id="t">Voyage calculation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5" id="t">Cargo Lifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-6" id="t">Performance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-7" id="t">Pool Rules</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tabs-8" id="t">Additional Pool Point</a></li> 
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
          <div id="totalpp_tab_main" ></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
           <div id="vessel_tab_main" ></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#41" id="1">Standard Voyage #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#42" id="2">Standard Voyage #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#43" id="3">Standard Voyage #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#44" id="4">Standard Voyage #4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#45" id="5">Standard Voyage #5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#46" id="6">Standard Voyage #6</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-5">
          <div id="cargolc_tab_main" ></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-6">
         <div id="performance_tab_main" ></div>
        </div>
            <div id="tabs-7">
         <div id="poolrules_tab_main" ></div>
         </div>
         <div id="tabs-8">
         <div id="additionalpp_tab_main" ></div>
        </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: add one css like **.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li{ display:inline-block}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add to your CSS:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without diving into jquery tabs, here is a quick fix:
http://jsfiddle.net/0m2zdo20/2/

Just added a css to remove theses dots.

```
#tabs-4 > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
}
```